Audio sink missing after suspend (hibernate)
When I return after suspending (hibernate) my laptop, the audio sink for the built-in speakers is missing. After I change the output device in the settings menu to 'speaker' the sink shows up again when I execute list short sinks. However, my goal is to set the default sink to the speaker sink after hibernate. How can I get the missing sink back after returning from hibernate (without having to change the output device manually via the settings menu)?
After returning from suspend/hibernate:
$ list short sinks
4626    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__HDMI3__sink PipeWire    s24-32le 2ch 48000Hz    SUSPENDED
4627    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__HDMI2__sink PipeWire    s24-32le 2ch 48000Hz    SUSPENDED
4628    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__HDMI1__sink PipeWire    s24-32le 2ch 48000Hz    SUSPENDED
**5443  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__Headphones__sink    PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED**

After changing the output device to 'speaker' via the settings menu:
$ list short sinks
4626    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__HDMI3__sink PipeWire    s24-32le 2ch 48000Hz    SUSPENDED
4627    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__HDMI2__sink PipeWire    s24-32le 2ch 48000Hz    SUSPENDED
4628    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__HDMI1__sink PipeWire    s24-32le 2ch 48000Hz    SUSPENDED
**4629  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__Speaker__sink   PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING**

Note that at the settings menu, only Speaker and HDMI is available:

EDIT:
I fixed it myself by following these steps:

pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device="hw:0,0" sink_name="analog_sink"
pactl set-default-sink analog_sink
Change the output device to 'speaker' via the settings menu (needed to be done once)

